# What is the query to make a grouping like this?

Tags: mysql

I have a table that look like this:

| order_id | qty |

| -------- | --- |

| 00001    | 27  |

| 00002    | 17  |

I want to make something like this

| order_id | qty | 20  | 5   | 3   | 1   |

| -------- | --- | --  | -   | -   | -   |

| 00001    | 27  | 1   | 1   | 0   | 2   |

| 00002    | 17  | 0   | 3   | 0   | 2   |

Has anyone know query to make a grouping like this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

working out each column by reduction (for want of a better word)

```
SET @N = 18;
SELECT FLOOR(@N/20) '20',
         FLOOR((@N-(FLOOR(@N/20)*20))/5) '5',
         FLOOR((@N-((FLOOR(((FLOOR(@N/20)*20)))) +
          ((FLOOR((@N-(FLOOR(@N/20)*20))/5)) *5)) 
         ) / 3) '3'
         ;
```